# Talend - Limit Number of Rows Processed

Tags: talend, soql

I'm working with Talend ETL to transfer data between two Salesforce Orgs. I'm trying to run preliminary tests to make sure everything is setup properly.

Is there a way to limit the number of rows being transferred? The database has over 50,000 rows, and I only want to send over 15 or 20.

Thank you.

Comment: Add a tSampleRow before you output component and specify in the Ecart value "15,20"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Talend side, you can use tSampleRow to only process a limited number of rows which were retrieved . For example you can use a line number range to only process rows 1-50.

Comment: To get only one result just put "1" et the Ecart value